# ControlMode not set error for some users

Tags: infopath, permissions, error, form

I have a page with an Infopath Form Web Part at server/Lists/listname/UserUpdateForm.aspx. When I link to this page and pass an item ID in the querystring using my account with full control permissions it functions as intended.

However, when using a test user account, clicking the same link returns a "ControlMode not set" error. The test user is able to access other pages in the same directory and has edit/create permissions in a custom permissions level.

where should I be looking to start to fix this problem?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If it is "for some users", then I would have tried to [clear Infopath cache](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/44467), disabled form's offline availability on client machines/directories of those users

[image: Uncheck Allow to fill out this form if data is unavailable]