# Change name of infopath form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, forms-services

We have a bunch of archived reports in a document library which are linked to an Info path template. That template has become corrupted but luckily we have a working copy of this in a backup folder.

So we are looking to delete the corrupted XSN file and bring in the working XSN file, the problem is as follows:

1. Cannot delete the corrupted XSN file, each time we delete it reappears!?
2. If we raname the corrupted XSN file, all the related XML document files update their reference to the rename file!
3. I CAN modify the XML files to point to the working XSN file and all is well But I have over 800 XML files which I would rather NOT have to manually edit

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand why are you deleting XSN file instead of opening your backuped XSN template, saving it and republishing from its backup copy (and then [relinking XML forms](https://web.archive.org/web/20151119050803/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/infopath/archive/2006/11/01/relinking-forms-and-form-templates.aspx) to a newly published template)?

Related post you might find helpful:

- [Restored infopath forms still opening using the new template.xsn?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44432/restored-infopath-forms-still-opening-using-the-new-template-xsn/44467#44467)

Some other thoughts to try:

- If the Infopath forms are set to be opened in Filler (it is in library settings, under advanced settings, to open the browser or client), you might want to try repairing Microsoft Infopath and/or [clearing Infopath cache](https://web.archive.org/web/20110514005609/http://office.microsoft.com:80/en-us/infopath-help/command-line-switches-for-infopath-HP010148328.aspx) on (all) client machines

Comment: The main reason was that I had 700 xml files all referencing the XSN...worked out a way to do it though by runing a script on the XML to update them to point to working XSN.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you don't need to rename or delete the old one , only what you need to overwrite the corrupted templated with the backup template by

- Open the backup template via InfoPath.
- Try to publish it again to with the same name of old one to overwrite it.

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

- Open working copy of  template.xsn file from Info-path form designer
- Check all data connection.
- Publish to SharePoint libray.
- Publish in existing library

If It still not work then

1. Open working copy of  template.xsn file from Info-path form designer
2. Check all data connection.
3. Publish to SharePoint libray.
4. create new library while publishing.
5. add existing records in library using power shell